# Inner arrangement of PostgreSQL transaction

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I'm using PostgreSQL. My questions are about transaction.

Let I began the transaction and inserted a couple of rows in table. Now these rows are accessible inside transaction, and after `commit` they will be seen out of transaction too.

So, my questions:

1. how does PostgreSQL store intermediate states of tables?
2. how does PostgreSQL merge real database state with intermediate state from transaction?
3. suppose, I have a big transaction with many data manipulations (ins, upd, del) inside. When all these data modification operations are executed (during transaction or all at once after commit)?

Now I think answers are following:

3. operations are executed during transaction and...
4. ...their results are stored into temp tables, which (together with old database state) form intermediate tables accessible from transaction.
5. after commit temp tables are merging (don't know how) with old state and deleting.

Give me please the correct answers or links to docs(books) where I can find it.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "intermediate state"? PostgreSQL MVCC model is lightweight using xmin/xmax in tuple to store row transaction visibility (simple said) - all you need to know is in documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/mvcc-intro.html